# Delete From ,Statement Query Failure

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to delete from table login only two entries within a row and leave the remaining information, For Example . username and last_seen should be deleted but image_path should remain.

[image: Table Layout]

I've used the following examples below in attempts to carry out my desired outcome but keep getting an error as follows

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /var/www/html/website/logout.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/website/logout.php on line 12

Example 1

```
$sqlQuery  =  "DELETE VALUES (username , last_seen) FROM login WHERE username=?";
```

Example 2

```
$sqlQuery  =  "DELETE FROM login username ,  last_seen  WHERE username=?";
```

Example 3

```
$sqlQuery  =  "DELETE FROM login VALUES username ,  last_seen  WHERE username=?";
```

Example 4

```
$sqlQuery  =  "DELETE FROM login VALUES ('username') ,  ('last_seen')  WHERE username=?";
```

I think my query structure is incorrect hence the failure of my bind_param

My Code

```
$sqlQuery  =  "DELETE FROM login VALUES username last_seen  WHERE username=?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->bind_param("s", $username);
$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
```

Comment: You can format whole blocks of code with the `{}` toolbar button, there's no need to type markdown line by line.

Comment: Thank You , I will in future .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove only some entries, you should not use `DELETE` but `UPDATE` to your null value (if nullable). For instance

```sql
UPDATE login 
SET username = null, last_seen = null
WHERE username = ?;
```

`DELETE` is intended for deleting rows.